# How does one predict the methylation pattern?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, epigenetics, dna-methylation

Suppose, we have a double stranded DNA like

> 5' AG**C**TAGGAGAGA**CC**AGGTT**CC** 3'
>
> 3' T**C**GAT**CC**T**C**T**C**TGGT**CC**AAGG 5'

Where would the methylated cytosine be? Is there any randomness?

Comment: It is usually at CpG however there are non-CpG methylations too. It is not easy to predict. You can however use machine learning by training from existing experimental data.